# Nested generation of comparison operator with three-way operator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, spaceship-operator

Consider the following two overload `operator<=>` for `S`:

```
#include <compare>

struct S {};

int operator<=>(S, int) { return 0;  } #1
S   operator<=>(S,   S) { return {}; } #2
```

If I compare an object `S` with an `int`, the `#1` will generate the right operators for me, so expression like `S{} <= 0`, `0 < S{}` or `0 <=> S{}` would be just [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/vd7adP).

But if I compare an object `S` with other object `S`:

```
S{} < S{};
```

Then this will be rewritten as `(S{} <=> S{}) < 0`. Since `(S{} <=> S{})` will return an other `S`, we back to the origin problem: `S` compare with a `int`. At this time, we don't have `operator<(S, int)`, so `#1` would generate the right operator for me.

But surprisingly, none of the three compilers do this to me. GCC, Clang, and MSVC [all](https://godbolt.org/z/xbbPMc) reject `S{} < S{}` with the same error message:

```
no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'S' and 'int')
```

This makes me frustrated. Since the `#1` actually exists. Why the nested generation of the operator are not occurring here? What does the standard say? Is there a static constraint violation?

Comment: Your code is not legal in either case.  `<=>` is required to return `auto`, `std::strong_ordering`, `std::weak_ordering`, `std::partial_ordering`, or `bool`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Comment: Just change the return type of `<=>(S,S)` to `auto`, which conforms to the standard (as far as I can tell), and you still get the same behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's only for defaulted comparisons (and the `bool` there doesn't apply to `<=>`).

Comment: See further down the linked page (from @NathanOliver) for the return type for custom comparators  _"...There are three available return types:..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm not sure that means those are the *only* possible return types. At least, I can't find the relevant wording constraining that in the standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is ill-formed, although admittedly the error message is quite confusing.

The rule, from [[over.match.oper]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over#match.oper-8) is (emphasis mine):

> If a rewritten `operator<=>` candidate is selected by overload resolution for an operator `@`, `x @ y` is interpreted as `0 @ (y <=> x)` if the selected candidate is a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters, or `(x <=> y) @ 0` otherwise, using the selected rewritten `operator<=>` candidate. **Rewritten candidates for the operator `@` are not considered in the context of the resulting expression.**

The expression `S{} < S{}` is going to resolve to the rewritten candidate `(S{} <=> S{}) < 0`. The resulting expression will not consider rewritten candidates in its lookup. So when we do `S{} < 0`, that is going to look for *just* an `operator<`, and not also `operator<=>`. It can't find such a thing, so the expression is ill-formed.

```
<source>:8:14: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'S' and 'int')
    8 | auto x = S{} < S{};
      |          ~~~~^~~~~
```

In that sense, the error is literally true: there is no match for, *specifically* `operator<` with those operands. Although it would help if the error message had quite a bit more context explaining why it's looking for that (and I submitted a request to that effect in [99629](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99629)).